# Is there a way to pass objects from php to javascript like node.js does

Tags: php, node.js

I'm trying to port an app written in node.js to php for a client and I need to know if there is a way to pass objects from php to javascript like this:

```
<script>
    var a = <%- instance %>;
    a.someMethod();
</script>
```

Comment: No I don't think you can.

Comment: What are you trying to input into the var?

Comment: Are you mainly just asking how to dump a PHP object as JSON data so you can use it in javascript on the client side?

Comment: what I really need to do is use a.someMethod()

Comment: For what it's worth, a node.js app is going to be very difficult to port to something as rigid as PHP.

Comment: @user2325753 you'll have to implement `someMethod` in javascript for it to be available to call on the client. Or do something RPC-style to run it on the server, as mentioned by @naomic below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to encode your data in JSON format first.

your data

```
$data = array(
  "foo" => "bar",
  "hello" => "world"
);
```

your script

```
<script>
  var data = JSON.parse(<?php echo json_encode($data) ?>);
</script>
```

---

- PHP [json_encode(**value**[, options])](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)
  this function has several options; read more in the docs for dictating a specific encoding behavior

  - `JSON_HEX_QUOT`
  - `JSON_HEX_TAG`
  - `JSON_HEX_AMP`
  - `JSON_HEX_APOS`
  - `JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK`
  - `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT`
  - `JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES`
  - `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT`
  - `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE`

---

- JavaScript [JSON.parse(**text**[, reviver])](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)
  this function takes a `reviver` and prescribes how the value originally produced by parsing is transformed, before being returned.

---

An alternative (to the above method) would be to provide an asynchronous JSON API

Your JavaScript could make a call

```
// using (e.g.,) jquery
var loadPeople = function(data) {
  console.log(data);
};

$.getJSON('/api/people.json').done(loadPeople);
```

Your PHP server would have to respond on this route

```
// response to /api/people.json
header("Content-type: application/json");
var $data = array(
  "foo" => "bar",
  "hello" => "world"
);
echo json_encode($data);
exit;
```

JavaScript console output

```
{foo: "bar", hello: "world"}
```

Comment: can I use methods from the object by encoding it into a json format

Comment: If you need to call methods on the object in JavaScript, you're looking for a "Remote Procedure Call" (or RPC). If you're unfamiliar with these concepts, there's a little bit of a learning curve on them, but you might want to start with PHP's natively-supported [xmlrpc](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xmlrpc.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can use json to pass your data from PHP to JS.

It could be a thing like that:

## php

```
$toJs['myObj'] = $myObj;
$toJs['whatElse'] = $otherVar;
```

## in your view

```
<script>fromPHP = JSON.parse('<?php echo json_encode($toJs) ?>')</script>
```

## script.js

```
console.log(fromPHP.myObj);
```

Comment: Important to note that this does not allow you to call you PHP methods on that object - it is a JS object after `JSON.parse`, and JS doesn't know about your PHP object or its methods.

Comment: @chesles you're right ! But if he just want to pass data, it works :)

Answer (score -2):

You can simply do this

```
<script>
  var a = <? = $phpvar;?>;
  a.someMethod();
</script>
```

EDIT: Nevermind. I misread and thought you meant 'variable' not object.

Comment: It should be `<?= $phpvar; ?>;` or better yet : `<?php echo $phpvar; ?>;` but it still wouldn't work.

Comment: You could delete your answer if you're not happy with it/don't think it's constructive, etc.

Comment: I'm new here. How exactly do I delete it? I just see share/edit/flag. Thanks.